# JavaScript generate password in html form

Tags: javascript

Generate password automatically by clicking generate button in html form. But the generated password should be from a list of passwords which is already given by the developer

```
<input name="password" type="text">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Generate" onClick="generate();">


<script>
function randomPassword(length) {
var passwords = ["text1","text2","text3"];
var pass = passwords[Math.floor(Math.random()*passwords.length)];
return pass;
}

function generate() {
myform.password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let passwordList is your sample password list provided by the developer, please replace it with original list you have

The id for input field of password is password.

Use the below code to fill that field with a random password out of developer provided password list

**Html :**

```
<input id="password" type="password"/>
```

**JS:**

```
var passwordList = ["password1","password2","password3"];
$("#password").val(passwordList[Math.floor(Math.random()*passwordList.length)];)
```

**If jQuery is not used:**

```
document.getElementById("password").value =passwordList[Math.floor(Math.random()*passwordList.length)];
```

Comment: Should provide a plain js equivalent since jquery isn't tagged here and OP is probably new to programming. However, I'd personnally let him express himself more on what he actually did and which problems he encountered. The only thing that separates thrash forums from SO is the quality of Q/A. We should avoid answering "please do that for me" requests. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Here Check it out

https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/tq6xwea2/

```js
var pwd = $("#pwd")
var button = $("button")
var len = $('#Length')
var A_Z = $('#A-Z')
var a_z = $('#a-z')
var num = $('#0-1')
var sc = $('#SpecialChars')


// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  pwd.html(CreateRandomPassword( len.val() ,A_Z.is(":checked"),a_z.is(":checked"),num.is(":checked"),sc.val()));
})

function CreateRandomPassword(Length, isUpperAlpha, isLowerAlpha, isNumaric ,SpecialChars)
{
  var _allowedChars = "";
  if (isUpperAlpha != false)
    _allowedChars += "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  if (isLowerAlpha != false)
    _allowedChars += "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  if (isNumaric != false)
    _allowedChars += "0123456789";
  _allowedChars += SpecialChars;
  if(!Length)
    Length = 8
  var chars = "";
  allowedCharCount = _allowedChars.length;
  if(allowedCharCount == 0)
   return " ";
  for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
  {
    chars += _allowedChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(allowedCharCount))];
  }
  return chars;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p id="pwd">Password</p>
  <button>Generate Password</button> <br /> <br />
  <label>Length <input type="range" min="0" max="20" id="Length" value="8"> </label>  <br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id='A-Z' checked> A-Z</label>  
  <label><input type="checkbox" id='a-z' checked> a-z</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id='0-1' checked> 0-1</label>
  <label>Additional Char <input type="text" id="SpecialChars" value="@#$%"> </label>  <br/>
</div>
```